# How can I get numbers of CPU of Sun Solaris by command?

Tags: solaris

I can use 'prtdiag' to get number of CPU by prtdiag command.

```
$ prtdiag
System Configuration:  Sun Microsystems  sun4u Sun Fire 6800
System clock frequency: 150 MHz
Memory size: 4096 Megabytes

========================= CPUs 
===============================================

             CPU      Run    E$   CPU      CPU
FRU Name    ID       MHz    MB   Impl.    Mask
----------  -------  ----  ----  -------  ----
/N0/SB1/P2    6      1200   8.0  US-III+  11.0
/N0/SB1/P3    7      1200   8.0  US-III+  11.0
/N0/SB3/P2   14      1200   8.0  US-III+  11.0
/N0/SB3/P3   15      1200   8.0  US-III+  11.0
```

But, I don't know is there any command could get the number (4 in this example)to let my script use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With modern CPUs and their multi-core, multi-thread technologies, you need to define more precisely what you want to count but in your case, `psrinfo` better suits the job:

```
psrinfo -p
```

Note that `prtdiag` wasn't designed to be parseable and might return a very different output depending on the hardware.

Comment: For numbers of cores/threads, I often do `psrinfo -v | grep -c on-line` which isn't the cleanest solution, but it's always worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple set of pipes using `psrinfo`:

```
psrinfo -v | grep ^Status | tail -1 | awk '{x = $5 + 1; print "CPUs: " x;}'
```

Example output:

> CPUs: 6

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
prtdiag | grep -c "^/"
```

To use the resulting value in a script, use `$(prtdiag | grep -c "^/")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good script to find all the CPU, cores, virtual CPU (threads)

https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/solaris_show_me_the_cpu

Comment: Adding the script from the link would improve the answer.  Links do break and then your answer is of no use.